# Error when using react-native-gesture-handler

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native

**When I am trying to use react-native-gesture handler I am getting the following error:**

: While trying to resolve module 'react-native-gesture-handler' from file '/Users/user/Project/index.js', the package '/Users/user/Project/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/package.json' was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a 'main' module field that could not be resolved ('/Users/user/Project/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/index.js'. Indeed, none of these files exist: [...]

**My index.js file:**

```
/**
 * @format
 */
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { NavigationContainer, StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import React from 'react';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import Logsg from './screens/logsg.js';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

const AuthStack = () => {
return(
 <NavigationContainer>
     <Stack.Navigator>
         <Stack.Screen name="Logsg" component ={Logsg}/>
     </Stack.Navigator>
 </NavigationContainer>
)
}


AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => AuthStack);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem, turned out that I did not set it up correctly on the native side.

Make sure to follow these instructions:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/